# How to set Matlab not to use or use always regional number formatting?

Tags: matlab, internationalization

My Matlab sometimes uses regional number formatting, and sometimes does not. May I ask it to do this always or may be not to do this at all?

[image]

As you see, it uses comma as decimal separator in one line of property editor and uses period as separator in neighboring lines.

Comment: What kind of formatting there is if you call the `Position` variable in the workspace?

Comment: I think you should report this as a bug at matlab center. Try to reproduce this using disp on an array and a scalar value, see if the problem is related to this. But it looks like it is a problem while displaying the values with sprintf %d and %f. Check if you print `sprintf('%d',value)` and `sprintf('%f',value)` if it will use comma or point.

Comment: I agree with @Werner, that looks like a bug to me. It should display either commas or periods, not a mix. What version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: @SamRoberts Matlab 2013 alpha

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, this is not a feature but a bug.

I have tried to reproduce it in version 2012b, but was unable to input non-integer numbers for `x`, `y` and `z`. If this was not possible before it would explain why it has gone unnoticed until now.

So, please post a bug report and it will probably be fixed in one of the the next versions that is published.